# Vue.js webpack - How to use themify-icons?

Tags: vue.js, webpack-2

I added the package

```
yarn add themify-icons-sass
```

then in my component , I imported it in the script and in the style

```
 <script>
 ....
import 'themify-icons-sass'

 <style lang="scss" scoped>
    @import 'themify-icons-sass/themify-icons';
    ...
```

but I get a build error

```
 This dependency was not found:  

 * themify-icons-sass in ./node_modules/babel-loader/lib!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=script&index=0!./src/components/HelloWorld.vue

 To install it, you can run: npm install --save themify-icons-sass
```

Where am I wrong in the import ?  thanks for feedback

**UPDATE**

First, if I want o import it from ./node_modules , then the @import should NOT BE in a scoped style...
So I moved it to a global style in my App.vue

```
<style lang="scss">
  @import "~themify-icons-scss/scss/themify-icons.scss";
  #app { ...
```

Then I got an erro , the node-sass/vendor directory was not bulit.. so I add to rebuild node_sass

```
 yarn add node-sass --force
```

Now it's taking in account the package but I get another error related to the relative path to the fonts:

```
    These relative modules were not found:
    * ../fonts/themify.eot in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-
    loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
    * ../fonts/themify.eot?-fvbane in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasIn
    lineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
    * ../fonts/themify.svg?-fvbane in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasIn
    lineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
    * ../fonts/themify.ttf?-fvbane in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
    * ../fonts/themify.woff?-fvbane in ./node_modules/css-loader?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/style-compiler?{"vue":true,"id":"data-v-7ba5bd90","scoped":false,"hasInlineConfig":false}!./node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js?{"sourceMap":true}!./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/selector.js?type=styles&index=0!./src/App.vue
```

the themify-icons-scss file structure is the following :

**node_modules/themify-icons-scss**

```
fonts
    themify.eot
    themify.svg
    themify.ttf
    themify.woff
scss
   _core.scss
   _extras.scss
   _icons.scss
   _mixins.scss
   _paths.scss
   _variables.scss
   themify-icons.scss
```

**node_modules/themify-icons-scss/scss/themify-icons.scss**

```
@import "variables";
@import "mixins";
@import "path";
@import "core";
@import "extras";
@import "icons";
```

**themify-icons-scss/scss/_path.scss**

@font-face {
    font-family: 'themify';
    src:url('#{$ti-font-path}/themify.eot?-fvbane');
    src:url('#{$ti-font-path}/themify.eot?#iefix-fvbane') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('#{$ti-font-path}/themify.woff?-fvbane') format('woff'),
        url('#{$ti-font-path}//themify.ttf?-fvbane') format('truetype'),
        url('#{$ti-font-path}/themify.svg?-fvbane#themify') format('svg');
    font-weight: normal;
    font-style: normal;

this is where there is some issue... with the $ti-font-path  as defined in the variables, relative to the scss directory in the package..

**themify-icons-scss/scss/_variables.scss**

```
$ti-font-path: "../fonts" !default;
$ti-class-prefix: "ti" !default;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED...

there is a nice recent package ( updated 3 months go, I forked it as an archive for me ..). see [themify-icons-scss](http://Frolki1-Dev/themify-icons-sass)

```
 yarn add git+http://github.com/Frolki1-Dev/themify-icons-sass
```

to solve the issue with the relative font path variable in the package _path.scss , I added the package  resolve-url-loader. ( see [resolve-url-loader on github](https://github.com/bholloway/resolve-url-loader)

```
 yarn add resolve-url-loader --dev
```

And as per the resolve-url-loader readme, as I want to use webpack loaders I inserted into build/utils

**build/utils.js**

```
exports.cssLoaders = function (options) {
  options = options || {}

  const cssLoader = {
    loader: 'css-loader',
    options: {
      sourceMap: options.sourceMap
    }
  }

  const postcssLoader = {
    loader: 'postcss-loader',
    options: {
      sourceMap: options.sourceMap
    }
  }
  // added  resolve-url-loaderr with sourceMap true
  const resolveUrlLoader = {
    loader: 'resolve-url-loader',
    options: {
      sourceMap: options.sourceMap
    }
  }
```

In my App.vue I can import (global , cannot be scoped)

```
<style lang="scss">
   @import "~themify-icons-scss/scss/themify-icons.scss";
   #app {
   ...
```

And I can check the themify-icons in my component template

```
<h2>Test Themify Icons</h2>
  <div class="row" style="margin-bottom: 30px;">
  <div class="col-4"></div>
  <div class="col-4">
    <span class="ti-email"> Email Me</span>
  </div>
</div>
```